# How to Implement the java.lang.Comparable interface on Roman Number Class?

Tags: java, junit, comparable

My next target is to implement Comparable Interface on Roman Number converter.

Maybe I need to use the interface like this:

```
public interface Comparable {
    public int compareTo(Object x);
  }
```

and after implement RomanNumber with this instruction:

```
public class RomanNumber implements Comparable<RomanNumber>
```

but I don't know as to continue. And more I need to test in JUnit this new method. I think this:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
  if(this.number>((RomanNumber)o).convertToInteger()){
    return 1;
  } else if(this.number<((RomanNumber)o).convertToInteger()){
    return -1;
  } else{
   return 0;
   }
  }
}
```

Here is the code under test:

```
public class RomanNumber{
    private String number;
    public RomanNumber (String number){
        validateState(number);
        this.number = number;
    }
    public int convertToInteger ()  {
        int decimal = 0;
        int lastNumber = 0;

        number = number.toUpperCase();
        for (int x = number.length() - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
            char convertNumber = number.charAt(x);
            switch (convertNumber) {
            case 'M':
                decimal = processDecimal(1000, lastNumber, decimal);
                lastNumber = 1000;
                break;
            case 'D':
                decimal = processDecimal(500, lastNumber, decimal);
                lastNumber = 500;
                break;
            case 'C':
                decimal = processDecimal(100, lastNumber, decimal);
                lastNumber = 100;
                break;
            case 'L':
                decimal = processDecimal(50, lastNumber, decimal);
                lastNumber = 50;
                break;
            case 'X':
                decimal = processDecimal(10, lastNumber, decimal);
                lastNumber = 10;
                break;
            case 'V':
                decimal = processDecimal(5, lastNumber, decimal);
                lastNumber = 5;
                break;
            case 'I':
                decimal = processDecimal(1, lastNumber, decimal);
                lastNumber = 1;
                break;  
            }   
        }
        return decimal;
    }

static int processDecimal(int decimal, int lastNumber, int lastDecimal) {
    if (lastNumber > decimal) {
      return lastDecimal - decimal;
    } else {
      return lastDecimal + decimal;
    }
}

private void validateState(String number){
  if (number == null)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null argument"); 
  if (number.isEmpty())
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Empty string");
  if (!number.matches("^M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$"))
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Roman number");    
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj){
  if ((obj instanceof RomanNumber)) {
    RomanNumber decimal = (RomanNumber)obj;
    if (number.equals(decimal.number)) {
      return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

 public int hashCode(){
  return number.hashCode();
 }
}
```

Comment: Well, you need to add the `compareTo` method, and you need to write the logic that compares two roman numbers. How would you know if one roman number is greater then another? Apply the same logic to the two objects you are comparing. And in the Unit test, you need to check that it works by comparing several pairs of roman numbers.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: thank you I understand the logic.

Comment: Please format your code so it fits without scrolling: Remove useless comments, spaces and most importantly simplify the code to show the exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

Giving you some starting points.

First unit tests could look like

```
@Test
public void testConversionToIntegerD() {
   assertThat(new RomanNumber("D").convertToInteger(), is(500));
}
```

And you would write many many tests like that; and make them more and complicated, to make sure that your conversion is correct. 
(ideally, you would have written those tests **prior** writing your conversion code).

And in order to compare to Roman numbers ... you know, you already implemented an conversion to Integer ... maybe, maybe that could give a hint how to compare to Roman numbers?! A test for that could look like:

```
@Test
public void testComparingDtoM() {
   assertThat(new RomanNumber("D").compareTo(new RomanNumber("M")), is(-1));
}
```

And a word of warning: you want to spend quite some time thinking about the "corner cases"; those nice roman numbers that are really complicated. 
Ideally, if you are doing this thing in a class room, you should have **other** people writing up testcases. When you do such things alone, there is always a certain chance that you overlook those "corner cases" both in tests and backing implementation.

(finally: i used **assertThat**, as this style of assertions allows for writing all kinds of great conditions; the only downside is that you need to use it with [Hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/) matchers like **is**. But seriously: it will be worth you time learning about that stuff)

Comment: @GhostCat: thank you very much for your suggest to create a test cases. But in the master class I need to put: public class RomanNumber implements Comparable<RomanNumber>
and after to Override CompareTo?

Comment: Ah, yes. You see, you already used `@Override` with equals(), so I assumed that you were familiar with that. But correct, in order to make your Roman number a comparable, you have to implement that interface.

Comment: @GhostCat: I can show you the previous test cases for the other methods, if you have interest.

Comment: @InExperience I don't think that is required. One final note ... now that you got the idea of how to compare: you don't need to implement the -1, 0, 1 yourself. Just convert your romans to Integers; and return what integerValue.compareTo(integerValue) computes!

Comment: Sorry if my requests are simple but I'm starting to understand the Java language.

Comment: Thats fine. And feel free to accept my answer in case it answered all your questions ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat: Ok thank you, just to compare without the implementation of -1, 1, 0.

Comment: @GhostCat: sorry but with your suggest I have an error regard this: public void testConversionToIntegerD() {
    assertThat(new RomanNumber("D").convertToInteger(), is(500));
 }
 
the method is(int) is undefined on RomanNumber Test

Comment: *is* is a hamcrest core matcher. I recommend using those together with **assertThat**; but that requires some special setup in your project (simply use a search engine and look for Junit, hamcrest matchers ...). In case you dont get it to work, you could also do something like assertEquals(...convert, 500) or so.

Answer (score 0):

this is my logical idea:

```
 public int compareTo(RomanNumber other){                
               // Compare RomanNumber
             if (this.convertToInteger()<other.convertToInteger())
                 return -1;
             if(this.convertToInteger()>other.convertToInteger())
                 return 1;
            return 0;
```

and for the JUnit test:

```
    // TODO test instance comparison
@Test
public void shouldCompareInstances() {

    RomanNumber rn1 = new RomanNumber("M");
    RomanNumber rn2 = new RomanNumber("MM");
    Assert.assertTrue(rn1.compareTo(rn2) == -1);
}
```